# Set a:hover based on class

Tags: html, css, colors, hover, anchor

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <a class="main-nav-item" href="home">home</a>
    <a class="main-nav-item-current" href="business">business</a>
    <a class="main-nav-item" href="about-me">about me</a>
</div>
```

In CSS, I want to set the `a:hover` for these menu items to a particular color. So I write:

```
.menu a:hover
{
    color:#DDD;
}
```

But, I want to set this `a:hover` color only for those `<a>` tags with the class *main-nav-item* and not the *main-nav-item-current*, because it has a different color and shouldn't change on hover. All `<a>` tags within the *menu* div should change color on hover except the one with the *current* class.

How can I do it using CSS?

I tried something like

```
.menu a:hover .main-nav-item
{
    color:#DDD;
}
```

thinking that only ones with main-nav-item class will change color on hover, and not the current one. But it is not working.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Try this:

```
.menu a.main-nav-item:hover { }
```

In order to understand how this works it is important to read this the way the browser does.  The `a` defines the element, the `.main-nav-item` *qualifies* the element to only those which have that class, and finally the psuedo-class `:hover` is applied to the qualified expression that comes before.

Basically it boils down to this:

> Apply this hover rule to all anchor elements with the class `main-nav-item` that are a descendant child of any element with the class `menu`.

Comment: It worked! :) Can you explain how that CSS selector is interpreted by the browser? Like in words. So that I know the logic and it'll be helpful for other CSS I write...

Comment: In words, that selector would be: “all <a> tags with a class of main-nav-item, and an ancestor with a class of menu, that are in the hover state (i.e. have the mouse cursor on top of them)”.

Answer (score 12):

Cascading is biting you. Try this:

```
.menu > .main-nav-item:hover
    {
        color:#DDD;
    }
```

This code says to grab all the links that have a class of main-nav-item AND are children of the class menu, and apply the color #DDD when they are hovered.

Comment: Another way of doing it. Will check it out too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Set a:hover based on class you can simply try:

```
a.main-nav-item:hover { }
```

Answer (score 1):

how about 
`.main-nav-item:hover`

this keeps the specificity low

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.div
{
text-decoration:none;
font-size:16;
display:block;
padding:14px;
}

.div a:hover
{
background-color:#080808;
color:white;
}
```

lets say we have a anchor tag used in our code and class"div" is called in the main program. the a:hover will do the thing, it will give a vampire black color to the background and white color to the text when the mouse is moved over it that's what hover means.

Answer (score 1):

I found if you add a `!important`, it works when previously it didn't.

```
    a.main-nav-item:link {
      color: blue !important; 
    }
    a.main-nav-item:visited {
      color: red !important; 
    }
    a.main-nav-item:hover {
      color: purple !important; 
    }
    a.main-nav-item:focus {
      color: green !important; 
    }
    a.main-nav-item:active {
      color: green !important; 
    }
```

Also, I've read somewhere that the order is important. The mnemonic "LoVe HaTe" helps you remember it: link -> visited -> hover -> active

Comment: How did you figure out that adding !important at the end forces it to add the hover color? Thank you! This worked for me. +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

One common error is leaving a space before the class names.  Even if this was the correct syntax:

```
.menu a:hover .main-nav-item
```

it never would have worked.

Therefore, you would not write

```
.menu a .main-nav-item:hover
```

it would be

```
.menu a.main-nav-item:hover
```