# Apply :hover styling to all elements that have the same class

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to apply a hover effect to all `button` tags that have the class `dialog-btn`. I've tried `.dialog-btn:hover{background-color:gold}` but that doesn't work. I've also tried other suggestions to similar questions but still no luck. Can someone please clarify how I can do this?

Neither of the two examples below works.

```css
button.dialog-btn:hover {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="dialog-btns">
  <button class="dialog-btn" id="yes">Ref Match</button>
  <button class="dialog-btn" id="about">About</button>
</div>
```

```css
.dialog-btn:hover {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="dialog-btns">
  <button class="dialog-btn" id="yes">Ref Match</button>
  <button class="dialog-btn" id="about">About</button>
</div>
```

EDIT 2:

```
 #yes{
    background-color:green;
 }
 #about{
    background-color:purple;
 }
```

The code above appears to overwrite the `.dialog-btn:hover` code above. Why is that?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve], not a tiny fragment of CSS with no HTML.

Comment: Your code .. ....'

Comment: _"Can someone please clarify how I can do this?"_ - using CSS alone: Not at all. (_Maybe_ if all buttons had a common parent, then hovering the parent could color the child buttons - but that is probably not gonna work out in most layout situations.) This will need some JavaScript.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935820/set-ahover-based-on-class

Comment: I'm not even sure what the question is asking. There are two obvious ways it could be interpreted: "When a button is hovered, that button takes on a different background colour" or "When a button is hovered, ALL buttons take on a different background colour".

Comment: @Nimish, I tried the suggested answer to the question you linked before asking this one, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @Quentin, it's the first. I basically want every button that has the dialog-btn class to turn gold when hovered over.

Comment: Post your code then]

Comment: Code is Posted!

Comment: @ribarcheto94 — Both versions of your code work when I test it. Did you verify your [mcve]? Does the problem only occur with a specific browser / operating system combination?

Comment: your code works fine, something else may be overwriting your style

Comment: Fawad, you are right! I have CSS specific for each of the ids `yes` and `about` but I don't understand why that overwrites the class :hover styling

Comment: Include a [mcve] please. It's probably just CSS specificity at play.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072365/css-understanding-the-selectors-priority-specificity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your comments, i guess you want to have gold color on all of your buttons if you hover over parrent element.

If it is the case, you can do that

```
.dialog-btns:hover .dialog-btn{
background-color: gold;
}
```

Comment: `.dialog-btn:hover{...}` works only when I don't have styling for id `yes` and `about`

Comment: it is because id have higher specificity than class. Either you shouldnot use id or use `background-color: gold!important;`

Comment: Thanks! That took care of it!